# Call set of parent property when setting child properties

Tags: vb.net

So in my class 'myInfo' I have an aliased property 'HeaderInfo' that is a property as a class, where it is actually the Header of a much deeper class.

```
Private _header As myHeader
Public Property HeaderInfo() AS myHeader
    Get
        Return _header
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As myHeader)
        _header = value
        Someotherclass.Foo.Bar.AnotherThing.Header = _header
    End Set
End Property
```

myHeader is a class with properties like 'Name', 'ID', etc. that are all strings. So when I reference this property in something like a Windows Form, I do

```
Dim info As New myInfo()
info.HeaderInfo.ID = "ID HERE"
info.HeaderInfo.Name = "Name here"
```

It works to the extent that the instance of the info.HeaderInfo is setting all its properties correctly, but

```
Someotherclass.Foo.Bar.AnotherThing.Header = _header
```

never gets set inside the myInfo.HeaderInfo 'Set', because I'm not directly setting the property, I'm setting its subproperties in assumption that it would propagate. Am I not understanding how properties with a custom type work? Is there a way to propagate this?

Comment: You could assign the `myHeader` from `info` to `Someotherclass.Foo.Bar.AnotherThing.Header` after you set the properties in `info`, e.g. `Someotherclass.Foo.Bar.AnotherThing.Header = info.HeaderInfo`

Comment: @JohnWillemse Yeah I think I'm gonna do that. I am trying to do it in the Constructor of myInfo so it'll just act as a reference but it doesn't seem to work that way apparently.

Comment: No, the constructor is called before you set the properties and you are left with the same problem. Just "copy" the header info once the properties are set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this happen automatically, you would need to alter the setter for the properties in your myHeader type, and for that to work your type instances have to know about the specific instance of your myInfo type.

Let's look at why this doesn't work they way you hoped. To do that, I'll break apart this statement:

```
info.HeaderInfo.ID = "ID HERE"
```

When that statement is executed, first the `info` variable must be de-referenced to get the object instance it refers to.<sup>1</sup> When we have that object, we have to **get** (not set) the HeaderInfo property, so that we have a reference to the your myHeader object instance. Once we have the myHeader object, we call the setter on the ID property to complete the assignment.

Hopefully that clears up why this works the way it does. You do access the HeaderInfo property, but you only ever use the getter.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Side note: if you ever see the "Object reference not set to instance of object" this is what it's talking about: a variable or property that you did not expect in an expression was Nothing/null.</sub>

Comment: Cool. I think I understand but the way that my project is set up, it wouldn't really be possible to do it that way. I think what I'll do is just make it so they create a new instance of the Header, fill out the information, then set that instance to the Public Property.